# How to write a dict of dataframes to one excel file in Pandas? Key is sheet name, Value is the dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am having much trouble trying to read in a large excel file (.xlsx), and write some of its tabs/sheets to a smaller excel file.

In one class, I get return a dict of dataframes. The key is the respective sheet/tab that the dataframe came from, type string. The value is the actual dataframe, with all of its original columns, type DataFrame. In this class, I extract certain dataframes from the original excel file.

I am able to print out my key:value pairs after extracting the dataframes of my choice, and it all looks fine. However, I believe that my real problem is writing the actual data to 1 excel file. I only get the first dataframe, without the sheet name that it came from (it becomes the default 'Sheet1'), and nothing else.

Here is the code that writes my dict to an excel file:

```
 def frames_to_excel(self, df_dict, path):
    """Write dictionary of dataframes to separate sheets, within 
        1 file."""
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter')

    for tab_name, dframe in df_dict.items():
        dframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=tab_name)

    writer.save()
```

- "path" is the select output path to write the whole dict to a xlsx fle.
- "df_dict" is the dict of dataframes.

Comment: weird. According to the docs you're doing everything right http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html

Comment: Just ran your code (with the example dataframes given in the link I posted) and it worked fine. Can you check that the `path` and `df_dict` passed are correct? What version of pandas `pd.__version__` are you using?

Comment: My Pandas version is the newest one, 0.23.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sorry for the confusion. My bug was not at all in the code I posted, or any of the classes that parse the data from the original excel file. The problem was this line of code:

```
 excel_path = re.sub(r"(?i)original|_original", "_custom", os.path.basename(excel_path))
```

- By doing the basename function from the os library, I was only using the file name, instead of the entire full path:

  writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='xlsxwriter')

-Therefore, I was not writing the correct data to the full path, and I was looking at old data from my programs output, from about 5 days ago. Thanks for everyones help.

The fix (use the proper full path that you expect):

```
excel_path = re.sub(r"(?i)original|_original", "_custom", excel_path)
```